# Failed to resolve module specifier "vee-validate". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

We don't use `npm` since we work on `Django` project but we use `VueJS` in templates. Now we use successfully `vee-validate` and I need to override error messages. The problem is that I can't find other way than `importing` and I can't do that this way.

I tried to create a new `<script type="module">` which obviously doesn't work:

```
Failed to resolve module specifier "vee-validate". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

This is my code.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@2.0.0-beta.25"></script>

<script type="module">
    import {localize} from 'vee-validate';

    localize({
        en: {
            messages: {
                required: 'xxxxxxxx',
                min: 'this field must have no less than {length} characters',
                max: (_, {length}) => `this field must have no more than ${length} characters`
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Do you have any ideas how to override the messages?

Comment: The statement "We don't use npm since we work on Django"  likely reflects a fundamental misunderstanding. It is common for projects to use both client-side and server-side package managers for their respective dependencies

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, but for now, this is the simpliest solution. Just to import vue into every page we need. Is there a way to make this work without npm? We use also Django templates alongside DRF.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make it work. download vee-validate, place it under your webroot,  and import  It using a relative path as indicated by the error message.

Answer (score 1):

VeeValidate can work just fine included in `<script>` (as shown in the [docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/overview.html#via-script-tag))

Once included, the global `VeeValidate` object is available. This will work if you use **non beta** version (for example [2.0.9](https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@2.0.9/dist/vee-validate.js)) (is there a raeson to use **old** and **beta** version ?)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
VeeValidate.Validator.localize({
        en: {
            messages: {
                required: 'xxxxxxxx',
                min: 'this field must have no less than {length} characters',
                max: (_, {length}) => `this field must have no more than ${length} characters`
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately there is not many examples for `script` usage in the docs, so you must explore the API yourself (just do `console.log(VeeValidate)`). Working with NPM versiou would be easier 100%...